# Native Select of Locale in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using **Vaadin**. I want to use Native Select to switch between locales.

```
@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    UI.getCurrent().setLocale(loc);
}
```

I wanted to use `event.getProperty()` but "loc" have to be Locale type. How can i get value of native select and convert it into Locale type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that you are populating `NativeSelect` like this:

```
  nativeSelect.addItem(Locale.ENGLISH);
  nativeSelect.addItem(Locale.GERMAN); 
  ...
  // you can also use setItemCaption(objectId, caption) method to give humanized  
  // caption to each item in NativeSelect.
```

After that, you can add a `Property.ValueChangeListener` to the `NativeSelect` component:

```
  nativeSelect.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override   
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            Locale loc = (Locale) event.getProperty().getValue();
            UI.getCurrent().setLocale(loc);
        }

  });
```