# ItemSetChangeEvent getting value of event

Tags: java, vaadin

I have native select of Locales implemented like that:

```
NativeSelect selectLang = new NativeSelect();

        for (Locale locale : localeProvider.getSupportedLocales()) {
            selectLang.setItemCaption(locale, localeProvider.getLabel(locale));
            selectLang.addItem(locale);
        }
        selectLang.setValue(user.getLocale());
        selectLang.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        selectLang.addItemSetChangeListener(new ItemSetChangeListener() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4797561043434404341L;

            @Override
            public void containerItemSetChange(ItemSetChangeEvent event) {
                // Locale loc = (Locale)event.getContainer().getValue();
                // UI.getCurrent().setLocale(loc);
            }
        });
```

I wanted to use event.getContainer().getValue(), but method getValue() is undefined for the type Container. How can I get value of event?

Comment: what you are trying to do? You want to perform some action when an user selects a value from the NativeSelect box or when reordering of items in the selectbox. Which one do you want?

Comment: action when user selects a value

Comment: try `Property.ValueChangeListener()`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608819/native-select-of-locale-in-vaadin/14612113#14612113

Comment: @akuzma try the solution used above it suits your requirement

Comment: i used it in other project, but here I can't use addListener cause it's deprecate and here I have demand to not use deprecated methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use selectLang.getValue() if you want to get the current value of the nativeSelect in a method :

selectLang.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            selectLang.getValue();

        }
    });
```

Of course add "final" to your component.

Answer (score 0):

[SelectExample.java (dev.vaadin.com)](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.1/src/com/vaadin/automatedtests/featurebrowser/SelectExample.java)